# C enum binary compatibility

Tags: c, enums

ISO C standard says that type of enum size is implementation-dependent:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer
>   type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
>   implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the
>   values of all the members of the enumeration.

Then, if we have the following situation:

1. Some C library is distributed in public headers and binaries. The
   library provides some interfaces with enum parameters or returning enum values.
2. Users compile their source files with enum declarations from public
   headers - a compiler on a user side might use different size of enum
   (from size inside the library).

It might cause binary incompatibility when passing values from user code inside the library (or vice versa) - e.g. user code would rely on `int`, but library code would use `short` - we might have problems because some bytes of an enum variable returned from the library will be uninitialized when read in the user code. So if we are relying on standard in this respect, formally we could run into such kind of issuesю

Is it correct reasoning? Especially given the fact that many C libraries are distributed in the similar way: public headers + static/shared libraries.

Comment: It's certainly conceivable. Usually compilers on a given platform would strive to be compatible for exactly this reason, but you really need to ask about 
a specific platform to get an exact answer. Note that in C++ (but not C), you can now specify the storage type of an enum explicitly.

Comment: Welcome to the nightmare of admin system.

Comment: The very same thing can happen with any non-fixed width or sign types. Or structures that can have different padding. Or what not...

Comment: Usually, these details will be specified in an ABI ([application binary interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) specification for the system.